# mapping path don't work, run script ssh interpreter pychram

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, pycharm

I have AWS, and I'm connecting to the server using pychram-ssh-deployment.
When I run script (using right click -> run, `ctrl+shift+F10`), I got the following error.

```
ssh://user@xxx.xx.x.xx:22/data/anaconda/bin/python /home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 0 0 C:/WC/trunk/content_dna/src/predict_hidden_layer.py
    globals = run_file(file, None, None)
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 35, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 11, in execfile
    stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable
  File "/data/anaconda/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 454, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/WC/trunk/content_dna/src/predict_hidden_layer.py'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

But if I change the Working directory and Script the Run/Debug Configurations  to `\home\user\PycharmProjects\content_dna\src` `\home\user\PycharmProjects\content_dna\src\get_imdb_keyword.py`

the script runs perfectly.

I want it to be automatic, I tried to add path mapping in three place:

1. Settings -> project interpreter -> Edit Project Path Mappings (three dot, available only in remote interpreter).
2. Run -> Edit Configuration -> Default -> Python -> Path mappings
3. Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration -> Mappings.

Now the weird thing is if I try to use Debug (right click -> Debug or `Shift+F9`), there is no issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

did you tick the option: show command line afterwards? I had similar problem. But after untick this option, my problem solved.

Comment: I know that unmarked "show command line afterwards"  solved it, but I need this option. I opened an issue in [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23974) , you can up-vote this issue.